# How can I compute F1 measure for each class, in Multiclass Classification?

Tags: machine-learning, nltk, computer-science, text-classification

I am using **SciKit**, as a library to work with classification algorithms like : NB,SVM.

here is a very nice and fine [binary classification implementation](http://zacstewart.com/2015/04/28/document-classification-with-scikit-learn.html) for "**SPAM** and **HAM**" *Emails*:

```
    confusion += confusion_matrix(test_y, predictions)
    score = f1_score(test_y, predictions, pos_label=SPAM)
   //note in my case 3-classes I do not need to set [pos_label]
```

If I have Three Classes like {SPAM, HAM, NORMAL} instead of two, then: how can I adapt that code to find **F1-Score** for each class and also for all classes as *average*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use classification report in sklearn to compute F-score for multiple classes.

```
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report as cr
gold = []
pred = []
# given a test set with annotated gold labels
for testinstance, goldlabel in testdata:
    gold.append(goldlabel)
    #clf is your classifier object with predict method
    predictedlabel = clf.predict(testinstance)
    pred.append(predictedlabel)
print cr(gold,pred, digits=4)
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem here is that the **F1 measure** is imho not really meaningful for multi-class problems. It is the harmonic mean between precision and recall.

**Precision** is the probability that a (randomly selected) positive classified instance is positive.

**Recall** is the probability that a (randomly selected) positive instance is classified as positive.

These definition are inherently binary. Typically I'd give the F1 measure for each of the classes separately. This allows you to also decide which kinds of failures are acceptable for you. From my personal experience I would actually give precision and recall. In you example the classification of a ham email as spam would be extremely harmful. Hence, Precision on SpAM is way more important than recall.

For a more broad overview also containing a list of measures you can check also http://rali.iro.umontreal.ca/rali/sites/default/files/publis/SokolovaLapalme-JIPM09.pdf

Comment: Yes, How can I implement recall and precision for each class , consider the above example,